# UIAutomation - TransformPattern.Resize and Move makes window disappear

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

When I call TransformPattern.Resize or TransformPattern.Move, the window disappears. I can still interact with the window's AutomationElement, but cannot see it on screen anymore. The AutomationElement reflects the changes made as well.

When I use Inspect, the same width/height/x/y values resize/move fine (i.e. window doesn't disappear).

My code:

```
TransformPattern pattern = (TransformPattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(TransformPattern.Pattern);
if (pattern.Current.CanResize)
{
    pattern.Resize(700, 700);  
}
```

(original size of window is (792, 800))

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Our team encountered this same issue when implementing Transform pattern methods on windows.

I was unable to find any documented bugs detailing this issue on Microsoft's side.

Two potential workarounds.

1) You can utilize P/Invoke and [SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) to essentially fake it, but get the same results.

2) Use P/Invoke calls to bring the window back into focus via [SetForegroundWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setforegroundwindow) and [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow).

Neither of these options are optimal, but they solved the problem for us and allowed consumers to move and resize windows with some wrappers around the P/Invoke calls.

It's also worth noting that TestStack.White devs (which I'm not affiliated with) have encountered the same problem:  https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues/205

Hope this helps!